# How to get the current URL in XSL

Tags: xml, url, xslt, xslt-1.0, client-side-scripting

I am trying to get the URL of the webpage XSL code is operating within, at this time I can place my own URL into the code and the results return as desired but I cannot find a way to get the URL dynamically. I need to do this in order to filter the results in a XML document

In essence I need something like

```
 <xsl:param name="url"  select= 
"'http://www.abc.com.au/~ljjohnso/SIT203/ass1/obaju/category-man.html?
type=shirt'"/>
```

to be

```
<xsl:param name="url"  select="'dynamically acquired url'"/>
```

Here is a copy of the code that is causing the issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:param name="url"  select="'http://www.abc.com.au/~ljjohnso/SIT203/ass1/obaju/category-man.html?type=shirt'"/>

  <xsl:template match='/'>
    <html>
      <xsl:variable name="type" select="substring-after($url, 'type=')"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/men[type=$type]">
      ...
      </xsl:for-each>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: XSLT 1.0 has no way to determine the URI of the processed XML. Which processor are you using and how are you initiating the transformation?

Comment: hi michael i'm using the XSLTProcessor as for how the transformation is initialised i use a javascript  function within a html file to load in and display the transformed data.

Comment: I am afraid that doesn't tell me much. Can't the javascript pass the query criterion as a parameter to the stylesheet?

Comment: If you run the XSLT client-side with Javascript and the `XSLTProcessor` API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XSLTProcessor then clearly you can set e.g. `proc.setParameter('', 'url', window.location.href)` on your XSLTProcessor object created with e.g. `var proc = new XSLTProcessor(); proc.importStylesheet(xsltDoc);`.

Comment: hey guys Martin is correct i was able to pass in the parameter as he states above. thank you both a heap.